# Cannot find symbol from ResultSet JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, syntax-error

I'm getting a cannot find symbol error and it points to the period right in `rs.getChars(1)` This code is all within a `try{}`.

There are three columns in the view table, title, item_id, and name. I'm just trying to query it but get a cannot find symbol on the line inside the start of the while loop.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt= 
conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Film_Sound_Track");
ResultSet rs = pstmt.getResultSet();

while(rs.next()){
    char item_id = rs.getChars(1);
}

rs.close();
pstmt.close();
```

Comment: There is no such a method as `getChars(int)`. There are however methods like `getString(String columnLabel)` and `getString(int columnIndex)`.

Comment: I'd like to suggest you familiarize yourself with the [Java API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). You could have answered this yourself by reading the API and noticing there is no such method.

Answer (score 2):

[`java.sql.ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) does not have a method `getChars`. You could use the `getString` method to retrieve a `String` and then extract the `char` from it:

```
char item_id = rs.getString(1).charAt(0);
```